# p5 Javascript Updating draw elements from Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, p5.js

I am very much a beginner programmer, but have managed to write a `python` script on a raspberry PI that successfully updates a Firestore database and pulls data using `JavaScript`.
I am then intending to use this data to draw items using `mappa` and p5 on a canvas/map.

I can console out the Firestore object and see the data but for the life of me I cannot seem to use this data in the `draw()` function of p5. or as a global variable? Here is a very simplified version of the code to what I'm trying to do.

```
db = firebase.firestore();
docRef = db.collection("Aircraft_data").doc("Firebird");
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
  console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
  b = doc.data()
  return b;
});

function draw(){

  text(b["Altitude"], 200, 200);

}
```

The most confusing thing is that I can console and see the data in chrome? 
[console img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Myd.png)

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `b` inside your `draw()` function?

Comment: I did try that in the `draw()` function and I have since found that the call to Firestore doesn't return the value quick enough before assigning to b so the `draw()` function fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are making async call, that's why you see the result in callback but not in following code section(s) (which most probably run earlier than callback).

P5 have [structure functions](https://p5js.org/reference/#group-Structure), draw() is one of them and is (by default) looping. Make your variable global and wait while it's been initialized (or some other ):

```
let myData; // make it global

function preload() {
    db = firebase.firestore();
    docRef = db.collection("Aircraft_data").doc("Firebird");
    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      myData = doc.data();
    });
}

function draw(){
    if(!myData){ //check whether data is loaded. Change condition to proper one.
        // if data is not yet arrived just return as draw() is looping
        return;
    }
    // now the data is arrived, myData is initialized, we can continue
    text(myData["Altitude"], 200, 200);
    //it is possible to stop looping now:
    noLoop();
}
```